# SPList.GetItems defaultView returning different fields than are actually present in the DefaultView of the list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am binding the SPList Items to the GridView by getting a DataTable, but I am getting entirely different fields in the DataTable from the fields which are present in the DefaultView of the SPList.

Not the field names changed (internal names/ title) , but the fields itself are different ones than are present in the list's default view.

I am using the following code:

```
GridView gd = new GridView();

            gd.DataSource = list.GetItems(list.DefaultView).GetDataTable();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is most likely due to the list.DefaultView either not being populated or correct. Try setting the value before you call get items. i.e..

```
SPView defView = list.DefaultView;
gd.DataSource = list.GetItems(list.DefaultView).GetDataTable();
```